# loading model with Three.js

Tags: javascript, three.js

I have a 3d model in the format of 3ds. I converted it to obj and then to js format. Now i want to load it in another js file. That's my code for the loading:

```
var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
loader.load( { model: "untitled.js", callback: createScene } );



function createScene( geometry ) {

geometry.materials[0][0].shading = THREE.FlatShading;
geometry.materials[0][0].morphTargets = true;

var material = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial();

var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
mesh.scale.set(50, 50, 50);

scene.addObject( mesh );
}
```

the web developer console show me the error: TypeError: a.split is not a function       Three.js:119

How can i fix this?
Thanks

Comment: what did you use to make the js file? (is it in the JSON 3 model format?)
ref:https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/JSON-Model-format-3.0

Comment: I used blender with different python addon files and exported it as a js file

Comment: I can't tell by looking at your code, but it seems to be related to the parsing, try commenting the contents of createScene and see if the error still occures. If there is still something wrong then the json creation was false.. You could maybe try to fix it manually...

Comment: the error still occurs, even with the createScene content commented

Answer (score 3):

Should be this instead:

```
loader.load( "untitled.js", createScene );
```

Comment: now it says geometry[0][0].materials is undefined. i think the untitled.js file is not okay